# Defining suppressions filter in checkstyle.xml vs pom.xml - maven-checkstyle plugin

Tags: maven, checkstyle

So here in my [case](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core), `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` is specified in both checkstyle.xml and pom.xml:

**checkstyle.xml:**

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
              <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </reporting>
    </project>
```

I'm not quite sure whether there's the need to define it in both files, one with `SuppressionFilter` module and `<suppressionsLocation>` tag in the pom.

And I want use https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/checkstyle.xml with other projects. However when doing so with `<configLocation>` set to `https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/checkstyle.xml` in the pom.xml, checkstyle-plugin fails with error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project webservices.rest: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Cannot set property 'file' to 'checkstyle-suppressions.xml' in module SuppressionFilter: InvocationTargetException: Unable to find: checkstyle-suppressions.xml -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project webservices.rest: Failed during checkstyle configuration

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed during checkstyle configuration

Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Cannot set property 'file' to 'checkstyle-suppressions.xml' in module SuppressionFilter

Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Cannot set property 'file' to 'checkstyle-suppressions.xml' in module SuppressionFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not quite sure whether there's the need to define it in both files

No need. If defined in the POM, maven will add it to the configuration behind the scenes.

> Failed during checkstyle configuration
>   Unable to find: checkstyle-suppressions.xml

It was unable to find your file to load.
It tries to find the file as a direct file system path (relative paths should be based off your current working directory), a URL, or a resource in your program. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter

Comment: Can you provide an example?